# Net Core React WebApi Auth Individual

Tags: c#, reactjs, authentication

I have a small problem getting into Net Core with React and Auth.

The first steps with React, without Webapi / Netcore are done, no rocket technology.

I've already worked with Net Framework MVC and Net Core MVC. Normally you can use the project templates.

The current project templates are however strange.

The project templates for react do not provide authentication, so why would anyone need authentication? In the Webapi templates there is only the Azure authentication, no Indvidual authentication.

There are several examples of the React integration, but most are not executable. Mostly outdated.

When scaffolding over npm you get a pure React app. Various templates in the net contain many things I do not need. First of all, one package manager is used to install the next, which in turn installs another one.

The solution seems to be creating two temporary projects, an MVC Project (with views) and a React project. Then build the right project together. I can not imagine that's how it's thought.

Now to the actual questions:

- Is there a reasonable documentation or a good book?
- How do you do it?
- Are you using the Nuget packages for React or are you directly integrating your React?

For a small app to get started I wanted to use the following:
- Net Core Webapi
- React without Redux
- JWT with NetCore Identity
- Dapper
- Postgresql

Is there a template for this? (Gladly also without Dapper / Postgres)

Comment: wow, after 5 months, how is this question not upvoted more? I am in nearly the same boat asking the same questions. were u able to find an answer? u start by saying that you have a small problem. It is a BIG problem. I used .net core React template. I added dapper and it connects to SQL great. But with Authentication, I don't know. I tried to get Nuget Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core but now what? I dunno.

Comment: To add Dapper, this works great:   https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-dapper-asynchronously-in-asp-net-core-2-1/

Comment: Unless there is a way to integrate .net Identity (as you would find in a normal MVC template) into the React .net core template, it seems that the path may be to go with 2 projects: ReactUI and a separate MVC (for webapi) project.  -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315092/split-react-and-webapi-in-2-projects?rq=1